# QTP does not identify / recognize java objects

Tags: automated-testing, java, qtp, qtp-11.0

I've been using QTP 11.0 on my PC quite a long time and had no problem with Java-apps (Java 7 Update 21 x86) identification (OS Windows 7 Pro 64-bit). But when I tried to install QTP on the server through RDP (also running under OS Windows 7 Pro 64-bit) I came across a problem with identification of java objects:

[image: Java objects identified as OS Windows objects]

So Java objects are identified as OS Windows objects (expected: JavaWindow --> JavaDialog).

---

If someone knows what to do please help!

Any good advice is also appreciated!

**Expected result:**

[image: Java object could be expected in details]

---

**RESEARCHES TILL NOW**

---

**First attempt**

I have installed QTP 11 patch `QTP_00699` for Java from [all QTP 11 Patches (downloadable from HP directly)](http://relevantcodes.com/qtp-11-0-patches/). **No result.**

Also did not expect any result cause I'm testing java 32-bit app (and on my PC it works fine without patch), but still there is a hope that it could change registry or system values in a proper way (maybe...).

---

**Second attempt**

Reversing java environment variables path (_JAVA_OPTIONS & IBM_JAVA_OPTIONS) and starting java-app from console prompt set to java bin directory

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre7\bin>javaws "C:\_qtp\testapp.jnlp"
```

According to the post in HP UFT Community Home [Object Spy sees a java app as window class instead of javawindow class?](http://community.hpe.com/t5/Unified-Functional-Testing/Object-Spy-sees-a-java-app-as-window-class-instead-of-javawindow/td-p/5828245). **No result.**

ALSO: the same action on my PC lead to QTP not being able to start.

---

**Third attempt**

Editing system registry. According to the post in HP UFT Community Home [QTP 11.00 not identifying java objects properly](http://community.hpe.com/t5/Unified-Functional-Testing/QTP-11-00-not-identifying-java-objects-properly/td-p/6461616).

Difference I've found there is no `QuickTest Professional` folder in `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Mercury Interactive` so I can not save anything, but I am happy file is deleted beforehand :) (on my local PC there is even no `Mercury Interactive` folder in `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\`)

And nothing was found for “%appdata%\HP” so there is nothing to rename! :) (my local PC has it)

After repair - **No result**

---

**Fourth attempt**

1. Uninstall QTP patch and QTP
2. One more time **Third attempt**

May be repair helped and:

3. `QuickTest Professional` folder was found in `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Wow6432Node\Mercury Interactive` so deleted it there.
4. `QuickTest Professional` was found for “%appdata%\HP” so renamed it.
5. Reboot
6. Install QTP (tested java-app visibility - **No result**)
7. Install QTP patch QTP_00699 `Support Testing on 64Bit Applications`. **No result.**
8. Install QTP patch QTP_00709 `Updates for HP QTP 11.00 [Critical]`. **No result.**

---

**Fifth attempt**

Reinstall JRE 1.7.21. **No result.**

I do not downgrade to 1.6 because 1.7 version is working fine on my PC with the same QTP installation. (Still I tried: did not help)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**TLDR:** Java v1.8 was installed on the server (It is not supported by QTP 11.0, only starting from UFT 12.02) check [QTP/UFT vs Java JDK Support Matrix](http://www.learnqtp.com/complete-support-matrix/).

---

**DETAILS**

---

**How to check**

1. Go to `Start` --> `Control Panel` and click on `Java [XX-bit]`. On the `Java Control Panel` select tab `Java` and press the button `View...`

On my local PC (Java is recognized by QTP):

[image: Java 1.7 is used to run jnlp]

And on the server:

[image: Java 1.8 is used to run jnlp]

Disabling checkbox `Enabled` against platform `Java 1.8` solves the problem of Java objects recognition in QTP 11.0.

2. There were two folders in `C:\Program Files (x86)\Java` directory:

   - jre1.8.0_65
   - jre7
3. In `Java Console Log`:

[image]

---

**Why this problem could happen**

Java 1.8 was installed some wierd way. And I paid no attention to support matrix cause it was obvious to me that I use the same version on local PC and on server. Why?

1. On app starting time it was always this picture:

[image]

Don't you know it's Java 1.8 starting right now :)

2. As you know from the **Second attempt** of this question I started jnlp-file right from the jre7 directory:

   C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre7\bin>javaws "C:_qtp\testapp.jnlp"
3. There was only Java 7 Update 21 on the `Programs and Features` panel:

[image]